# Criar uma sessão no PHP

Tags: php

Estou tentando fazer com que o sistema de login do meu site crie uma sessão para o usuário logado, fazendo com que apareça seu nome na página seguinte que ele logar, mas não está aparecendo. Segue o código:

**verificar_login.php**

```
<?php
session_start();  
$_SESSION['nome'] = $_POST['NOME'];  
$_SESSION['senha'] = $_POST['SENHA'];  

include 'bd.php';

if($_POST["NOME"] == "geral" && $_POST["SENHA"] == "geral"){
     echo
                "<script>
                 alert('Bem Vindo adm!');   
                 window.location.href='info_php.php';                
                 </script>";
}



$link = mysqli_connect($servidor,$usuario,$senha,$banco);

if(isset($_POST["NOME"]) && isset($_POST["SENHA"]))
    {
        if(!empty($_POST["NOME"]) && !empty($_POST["SENHA"]))
        {
                $sql = "select * from empresa where  NOME =             '".$_POST['NOME']."' and SENHA = '".$_POST['SENHA']."';";

                $result = $link ->query($sql);

            if($result->num_rows > 0) {

            $_SESSION['nome'] = $nome;
            $_SESSION['senha'] = $senha;

            echo
                "<script>
                 alert('Bem Vindo!');
                 window.location.href='index2.php';              
                 </script>";
            }               


            else{
                unset ($_SESSION['nome']);
                unset ($_SESSION['senha']);
                echo
                "<script>
                 alert('Login ou senha Incorreta!');               
                 </script>";

             }
```

**index2.php**

```
<?php
session_start();

if((!isset ($_SESSION['nome']) == true) and (!isset ($_SESSION['senha']) == true))
{
    unset($_SESSION['nome']);
    unset($_SESSION['senha']);
    header('location:index.php');
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>EVA system</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<body>
<span>Bem-Vindo, <strong><?php echo $_SESSION['nome']; ?></strong></span><br>
```

Comment: E quais as mensagens de alerta que aparecem?

Comment: la no começo logo quando vc inicia a sessão, se vc realizar um var_dump no $_POST['NOME'];  retorna o que?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss, os alertas funcionam corretamente, apenas a parte onde aparece o nome do usuário que não está funcionando aparentemente.

Comment: Por isso que pedi quais são os que aparecem, para saber quais partes do código são executadas.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss Bem Vindo! (quando efetuado corretamente o login)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As seguintes linhas estão estranhas ao meu ver:

```
 $_SESSION['nome'] = $nome;
 $_SESSION['senha'] = $senha;
```

As variáveis `$nome` e `$senha` não foram instanciadas, a session ficará sem dados nenhum nos respectivos campos. Você pode remover essas duas linhas, pois já está atribuindo os valores passados por POST antes:

```
$_SESSION['nome'] = $_POST['NOME'];  
$_SESSION['senha'] = $_POST['SENHA'];
```

Comment: Era esse o problema, muito obrigado!

Comment: Sem problemas, abraço!

Answer (score 0):

Jamais salve variáveis "sensíveis" na sessão sem usar alguma criptografia, esses dados muitas das vezes ficam expostos por cookies ou outras falhas do PHP.

Aconselho a aprender CodeIgniter, Laravel, Symfony ou Slim3 para o desenvolvimento de Apps em PHP.

Comment: Concordo com a primeira parte, agora a parte de expostos por cookies não faz sentido.